# await is only valid in async function Discord bot reaciton role

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, discord, bots

iam beginner i want to code reaction role on discord bot but its not work please help me

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    module.exports = {
name: "reactionrole",
description: "Sets up a reaction role message",
execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    const channel = "845246330678280212";
    const czechRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Czech");
    const slovakiaRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Slovakia");

    const czechFlag = ":flag_cz:";
    const slovakiaFlag = ":flag_sk:";

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setcolor("#e42643")
        .setTitle("Choose your State!")
        .setDescription("Choose your state!\n\n"
            + "${czechFlag} for Czech state\n"
            + "${slovakiaFlag} for Slovakia state");

    let MessageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    messageEmbed.react(czechFlag);
    messageEmbed.react(slovakiaFlag);

    client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.flag.name === czechFlag) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(czechRole);
            }
            if (reaction.flag.name === slovakiaFlag) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(slovakiaRole);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });

    client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.flag.name === czechFlag) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(czechRole);
            }
            if (reaction.flag.name === slovakiaFlag) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(slovakiaRole);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Can you point out where the error occurs in the code?

Comment: `execute` is not an async method, but you're using `await` inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line might be causing the issue:

```js
let MessageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
```

You can put an `await` statement only inside an `async` function. The statement above falls under the `execute(...)` function, which is not async.